# Import NodeTree from blender file during addon register

Tags: python, add-on, import, blend-files

I have a blender file with several `NodeGroup`s. I want to import those `NodeGroup`s into other files using an addon. During the `register` method of the addon, I call an `init` function which the following implementation:

```
def init():
    filepath = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/materials.blend/NodeTree/"
    print(filepath)

    bpy.ops.wm.append(filename="TestNode", directory=filepath)
```

This code fails with the following output:

```
/home/kdab/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/asdf/materials/materials.blend/NodeTree/
Exception in module register(): /home/kdab/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/asdf/__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/2.81/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 384, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "/home/kdab/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/asdf/__init__.py", line 52, in register
    materials.KDAB_custom_materials.init()
  File "/home/kdab/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/asdf/materials/KDAB_custom_materials.py", line 44, in init
    bpy.ops.wm.append(filename="TestNode", directory=filepath)
  File "/usr/share/blender/2.81/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 195, in __call__
    BPyOpsSubModOp._view_layer_update(context)
  File "/usr/share/blender/2.81/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 157, in _view_layer_update
    view_layer = context.view_layer
AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'view_layer
```

If I call that code from Blender console, it works fine. How can I make it work from the addon?

Comment: It totally answers why I cant do that, but I'm not sure how I can import the NodeGroups from other blend file. Should I postpone a call to an operator or something like that?

Comment: That sounds like good approach.

Comment: So finally I have change the code to import the file when necessary. In my case, I want to import a NodeTree to use it for a ShaderCustomNodeGroup, so in the init function of the ShaderCustomNodeGroup I do the import. Works fine